# How to return data from a json inside a json

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to return a JSON inside a JSON. I tried and I cannot figure it out.

**Controller.php**

```
$output_sum = json([
  "sold_price"=>1,
  "item_cost"=> 2,
  "fees"=>3,
  "profit"=>4
]);

return response()->json([
  'spreadsheet_grid'=>"hello",
  'spreadsheet_summary'=>$output_sum
]);
```

Comment: You are encoding it twice so you'd have to decode it twice.

Comment: Do you want to return the json as a string or as an object?

Comment: as an object @Jerodev

Comment: I wonder why you're doing this instead of creating one object and encode it.

Comment: No need to convert `output_sum` to `json` (i think)

Comment: @Zakaria Acharki Im new to this so could you give me an example appreciate it.

Comment: Why r you encode json twice?

Answer (score 4):

I think It will be better and simple to encode the whole array one time, like:

```
$output_sum = [
  "sold_price"=>1,
  "item_cost"=> 2,
  "fees"=>3,
  "profit"=>4
];

return response()->json([
  'spreadsheet_grid' => "hello",
  'spreadsheet_summary' => $output_sum
]);
```

The resulted JSON format will be like:

```
{
  "spreadsheet_grid":"hello",
  "spreadsheet_summary":
  {
     "sold_price":1,
     "item_cost":2,
     "fees":3,
     "profit":4
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's a sample @Sang